# Python editing in a list based on the data type of an element

Tags: python, object, types, numpy-ndarray

I have a list of mixed datatypes ( strings and objects):

```
mylist=['Buffet',
 'Buffet',
 'Buffet',
 'Buffet',
 'A la Carte',
 'A la Carte',
 'Buffet',
 'Buffet',
 'Buffet',
 'A la Carte',
 'A la Carte',
 array(['A la Carte', 'Buffet'], dtype=object),
 'A la Carte',
 'Buffet',
 'Buffet', 
...]
```

I want to replace this object type array item with just another string, for example the string "Both". 
Therefore I can have a homogenized list. How can I do that?
Thanks

Comment: Use isinstance method and loop the list to convert objects to strings

Answer (score 2):

Run through the list and check if the element is an instance of numpy.ndarray.

```
   for f in range(len(mylist)):
      if(isinstance(mylist[f],numpy.ndarray)):
        mylist[f]="Both"
```